# Swing: keeping reference to Color in components

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, colors

How do I programmaticaly update the color of N `JComponents` (background and foreground), by changing a `Color` variable `c` ?
**Example:**

I have 10 `JButton` and 5 `JCheckbox`. 
I have the variable:

```
Color mainColor = Color.RED;
```

I set all backgrounds and foregrounds to `mainColor`.
Now if I want all of them to be blue, `mainColor = Color.BLUE` will not work.
Normally I would do something like `mainColor.setRgb(0,0,255)`, but for whatever reason, `Color` does not allow this.

So what can I do? Other workarounds are appreciated as well.
The components are spread out accross a lot of panels and frames and some appear dynamically so I'd rather not keep a list. 
Also not all of them require both foreground and background to be painted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to reset the color on all the JComponents. For simplicity,  you could create a helper method that does it for you.

```
void changeMainColor(Color c){
    this.mainColor = c;
    for (JComponents jc : this.myComponentsList){
        jc.setForeground(c);
        jc.setBackground(c);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

If you do not want to keep a list of components manually, use the Observer pattern:

For even greater abstraction, use Publisher/Subscriber pattern. Everytime you change the main color you sill "publish" the fact. All the components that are registered as "subscribers"  to that event, will then be able to use the information provided (the color) in the event to do what they want (change background etc..)

I would suggest reading about them in the gang of four book (Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software), but some quick references are below:

https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/observer and 
https://abdulapopoola.com/2013/03/12/design-patterns-pub-sub-explained/

Comment: Thanks, but please read the whole question. I said I'm looking for a workaround.. I cannot keep a "myCompontensList" in my specific case. Also not all of them need both setForeground and setBackground

Answer (score 0):

Ugly style : subclass java.awt.Color, delegating to a real Color instance with a mutator for the delegate.